# Updating to a previous version of code with Fossil without a file called "Desktop.ini"

Tags: file, version, fossil

I am new in version control and Fossil. We are using Fossil to manage the version control of our C code. I need to come back to a previous version using the command "update version number", however it does not work because one of the files included in the previous version was the "Desktop.ini". When fossil tries to replicate that file it gets an error probably due to windows permissions. Is there any way to delete a file from previous checks-in? What is the other option? I can type "update file1 file2 file3.... version number" but that would be time consuming for all the files and I cannot see the way of updating everything except a single file.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: BTW you don't need to type the whole SHA of the version.  The first few characters suffice (usually 6, but even 4).  If there are more versions starting with those same digits, you will told so.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do (using the GUI, i.e., fossil ui) is go to the check-in(s) you want to remove files from, and click on each file to remove, then click the Shun option, and confirm.  Rebuild when done with all files.

The above should work.

To be sure, I just tried it on a sample fossil after changing a file to read-only so that the update would explicitly fail.  Shunning the file from the previous version(s) does not abort the update anymore.